# How many entities I pay when I use objectify first() method in datastore queries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I know that Datastore pricing quotas are based, for any query, on the number of entities retrieved. Now, if I write, using objectify, a query like this or a similar one:

```
Car car = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("vin >", "123456789").first().now();
```

do I pay for any entitiy that has vin > 123456789 selected by the query or only for the first one that I'm actually retrieving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datastore documentation on indexes says this:

> 1. Identifies the index corresponding to the query's kind, filter
>      properties, filter operators, and sort orders.
> 2. Scans from the beginning of the index to the first entity that meets
>      all of the query's filter conditions.
> 3. Continues scanning the index, returning each entity in turn, until
>      it
>
>    - encounters an entity that does not meet the filter conditions, or
>    - reaches the end of the index, or
>    - has collected the maximum number of results requested by the query.
>
> (source [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_definition_and_structure))

Since your maximum number of results requested by the query is 1 you only have an index scan with a single read which you would be billed for.

Note that indexes are ordered, therefor this would be a very short index scan and a really small operation.

On the other hand, you do not specify an order in the query. So, technically, the result could be any entity that qualifies your query. Usually you would want the biggest or smallest or whatever value within the qualifying range. Since indexes are ordered you should get the first entity in your index depending on the index order (ascending or descending).

Comment: But, if indexes are ordered, scanning for the first one wouldn't encounter the first entity that is just above the filter bar? If it's not so, how can I furtherly specify the query filter to behave this way?

Comment: i believe you would have to add an `.order("-vin")`. The question is if that requires an additional index.